# How to only filter chinese(special character set) in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

data source:

```
测试demo
demo1
中文2
```

output:

```
demo
demo1
2
```

I try to `select regexp_replace('测试中文demo','[\u0391-\uFFE5]','') from dual`,but no effect. And `\w` including the chinese, so don't use `[^\w]`.

Now I can think of  `select regexp_replace('测试中文demo','[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]','') from dual`.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I think you have a typo - `A-z` -> `A-Z`

Comment: Thanks, has been edit.

Comment: Try `select regexp_replace('测试中文demo','[' || unistr('\0391') || '-' || unistr('\FFE5') || ']','') from dual`. Not sure the range is really the one you need. Maybe you actually need `[\u4e00-\u9eff]` range?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried, still is invalid.@Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: Anyway, the idea is valid, I think. You just need to find the expression that works in JS. Tried `select regexp_replace('测试中文demo','[' || unistr('\4e00') || '-' || unistr('\9eff') || ']','') from dual`?

Comment: Or `\4e00` - `\9fa5`? There are different sources.

Comment: I try to `\0391`  - `\9fa5`is succeed,  `\4e00`  - `\9fa5` return`测试文 demo`

Comment: Ok, I added this range to the first regex_replace in my answer. I am not sure as for the second one that is aimed to match any Chinese Unicode character ranges since it contains composed chars from high/low surrogates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [*Searching Unicode characters in Oracle table*](http://debugguru.blogspot.com/2011/11/searching-unicode-characters-in-oracle.html):

> Normally with Regular expression, you can use `\x` or `\u` followed by hexadecimal code to search for any character. E.g. `\x20` will match space. But `REGEXP_LIKE` in Oracle does not support `\x`. You need to use [`unistr` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions204.htm) to convert the code to equivalent character and then use it with `REGEXP_LIKE`. E.g. `REGEXP_LIKE(source,'[' ||unistr('\0020')|| ']');`

So, you need something like

```
select regexp_replace('测试中文demo', '[' || unistr('\0391') || '-' || unistr('\9FA5') || ']','') from dual
```

Note: a better Chinese regex should include all the following ranges:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|Block                                   | ES6 Range   |   ES5 Range              |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|CJK Unified Ideographs                  | 4E00-9FFF   | \u4E00-\u9FFF            |
|CJK Unified Ideographs Extension A      | 3400-4DFF   | \u3400-\u4DFF            |
|CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B      | 20000-2A6DF | \uD840\uDC00-\uD869\uDEDF|
|CJK Unified Ideographs Extension C      | 2A700–2B73F | \uD869\uDF00-\uD86D\uDF3F|
|CJK Unified Ideographs Extension D      | 2B740–2B81F | \uD86D\uDF40-\uD86E\uDC1F|
|CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E      | 2B820–2CEAF | \uD86E\uDC20-\uD873\uDEAF|
|CJK Compatibility Ideographs            | F900-FAFF   | \uF900-\uFAFF            |
|CJK Compatibility Ideographs Supplement | 2F800-2FA1F | \uD87E\uDC00-\uD87E\uDE1F|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So, try

`select regexp_replace('测试中文demo','[' || unistr('\4E00') || '-' || unistr('\9FFF') || unistr('\3400') || '-' || unistr('\4DFF') || unistr('\D840\DC00') || '-' || unistr('\D869\DEDF') || unistr('\D869\DF00') || '-' || unistr('\D86D\DF3F') || unistr('\D86D\DF40') || '-' || unistr('\D86E\DC1F') || unistr('\D86E\DC20') || '-' || unistr('\D873\DEAF') || unistr('\F900') || '-' || unistr('\FAFF') || unistr('\D87E\DC00') || '-' || unistr('\D87E\DE1F') || ']','') from dual`

Comment: The`select regexp_replace('测试中文demo','[' || unistr('\4e2d')||unistr('\6d4b') ||unistr('\8bd5')|| unistr('\6587')||']','') from dual;` is succeed ,but `unistr('\0391') || '-' || unistr('\FFE5')` is invalid.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please check the range I created with the help of https://mothereff.in/regexpu. This should catch all the Chinese characters.

Comment: The latest answer return `ora-12728`.The `select regexp_replace('测试中文 demo', '[' || unistr('\0391') || '-' || unistr('\9fa5') || ']','') from dual`  is ok.

Comment: So, that does not match all Chinese chars or does it? Please let me know if I should remove that part from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_REPLACE`

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(YOURFIELD,'[^a-zA-Z'']','') AS outputfield
FROM YOURTABLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But it will replace the special characters, such as space.